# Is it possible to print a Swing component without Print dialog?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I would like to print a Swing component (Table Component) without user interference, so that the print dialog box doesn't show up.

Is that possible?

Comment: I wanted to print Table Component without print dialog box. Is it possible? If possible, let me know. Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggesting to read [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) tutorial,

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat(" Whatever");
MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat(" Page {0,number,integer}            Whatever");
     try {
         PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
         set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
         myTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer, false, set, false);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "JTable was Successfully "
                + "\n" + "Printed on your Default Printer");
     } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "Error from Printer Job "
                + "\n" + e);   
     }
```